# Post to the wall of an app page as the currently logged in user with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I hope I am using the right terminology but please for give me if I am not.  I am using the iOS SDK in an iPhone app.  I want to code for a user to make a post to the wall of an App page on Facebook.

**Permission** I get these permission

```
@[@"publish_actions", @"publish_pages", @"manage_pages"]
```

**Request** this is my request code

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
      initWithGraphPath:@"myAppKeyID/feed"
      parameters: @{@"message": @"This is my message"}
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {

         } else {

         }
     }];
```

I get an error response

> body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 200;
>               message = "(#200) Permissions error";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 403;

In the Graph API Explorer I can do exactly the same thing with these permissions and it works fine. I see a post from me on the wall of the apps page.

Can someone please help?

Comment: When you track the network calls made by the iPhone app, you should be able to see the exact call made by the SDK and that can help you figure out if things aren't being configured correctly on your iPhone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the answer. The above code is fine.  I was using the wrong app ID.